# Place images over another based on that image coordinates

Tags: css, image, components, overlap, angular8

I need to create an Angular 8 component that holds a big image that serves as a map and places dynamically smaller images on the former based on that image coordinates.
For instance: I have a room image in background. From server I know that my chair image is 20x20 px and it should be placed with center at 120x 300y relative to the room image.

How can I achieve that? I tried to use some css trick like wrapping the bigger one inside a relative positioned div, and the smallers insied absolute divs setting with NgStyle their style but it just places it at 0.0

For project requirements I can't use AngularMaterial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood properly your question, could be enough just to place your chair image relative to the background one. I would wrap your background in a container which will be the relative one for any other absolute inner element.

Something like that:

```css
.room-container {
  position: relative;
}

.chair {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 400px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="room-container">
  <!-- BG Image-->
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Hotel-suite-living-room.jpg" alt="">
    
  <!-- Chair image -->
  <img src="https://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/ekedalen-chair-brown__0516603_PE640439_S4.JPG" alt="" class="chair">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that made my day. Even if I tried that before this looked cleared to me and probably fixed my errors. Sadly I can't do this through ngStyle directive for some reason. I had to split styles individually (which I don't like much for code redundancy). Still this is the correct approach.