# Place images over another in VueJS/Vuetify based on that image coordinates

Tags: html, css, image, vue.js, primevue

My problem is similar to this one: [Place images over another based on that image coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306872/place-images-over-another-based-on-that-image-coordinates) , but it doesn't seem to work in VueJS and PrimeVue.

I'm trying to achieve the same thing but using a  with multiple  tags. Each area should have an image corresponding to a building, or the "chair" in the similar problem. The background image is using this map to know the clickable coordonates, because I want to be able to click on the buildings.

My code is the following:

```
<div class="map-container">
  <img src="../assets/Map_F.png" alt="city" usemap="#city" />
</div>

<map name="city">
  <area
    class="area"
    shape="rect"
    coords="1049,347,1104,428"
    alt="mainBuilding"
    href="mainBuilding.htm"
  />
</map>

.map-container {
  position: relative;
}

.area {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("../assets/building.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help :D